# SWIFT - Alamofire - Upload Video result as 0bytes

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload a video to a server. I can see the video created in my folder server however, the file is empty 0bytes.

The video is recorded from the mobile camera and I get the full path:

> Optional(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4A1D071A-5DEB-42BE-BAE5-2B45990B5CEF/tmp/capture-T0x144618b10.tmp.3BEOLf/capturedvideo.MOV)

When the video is recorded I have a button to send it to the server.

What am I doing wrong here? And how I can change the directory where my video will be saved?

SWIFT

```
@IBAction func sendVideoAction(sender: UIButton) {

let fileName = "myVideo.MOV"

        //let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
        let filePath = String(pathVideoToSEnd)
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            "https://example.com/uploadVideo.php?fileName=\(fileName)",
            file: fileURL)

}
```

PHP

```
<?php
// get the file data
$fileData = file_get_contents('php://input');
// sanitize filename
$fileName = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])", '', $_GET["fileName"]);
// save to disk
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
?>
```